# Верстка рамки с двумя блоками

Tags: css

[image: Рамка (красным отмечены 2 блока в которые будет производится ввод данных]

Подскажите, как можно сверстать данный элемент? красным отмечены два блока в которых будет находиться form.

Answer (score 1):

Основная идея такая:

```css
.container {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxTYY.png');
  width: 241px;
  height: 283px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}
.first-form {
  width: 114px;
  height: 43px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 127px;
  left: 65px;
}
.second-form {
  width: 74px;
  height: 41px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 217px;
  left: 84px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form class="first-form">Форма №1</form>
  <form class="second-form">Форма №2</form>
</div>
```